# While trying to setup Vagrant

Tags: windows, rubygems, vagrant

C:\VM\first_project>vagrant init ubuntu/xenial64                                                                                                                        Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                              6: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.1/gems/vagrant-2.3.1/bin/vagrant:105:in `<main>'                                                                         5: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.1/gems/vagrant-2.3.1/bin/vagrant:94:in` block in '                                                                 4: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.1/gems/vagrant-2.3.1/bin/vagrant:94:in `each'                                                                            3: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.1/gems/vagrant-2.3.1/bin/vagrant:95:in` block (2 levels) in '                                                      2: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:62:in `gem'                                                                1: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:323:in` to_spec'                                                            C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bcrypt_pbkdf' (~> 1.1) among 94 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)                                                                                                                                                             Checked in 'GEM_PATH=C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.1', execute` gem env` for more information

Comment: And the question is?  Also, what did you do with the line: **Checked in .... execute gem env` for more information**.  Did you try to do anything with it, and if so what ?

Comment: And pretty new to it and I didn’t alter or make any changes to any files. I get the errors while trying to install Ubuntu to work with.

Comment: I think you have to describe your problem a lot more. This isn't a site to copy paste your error log and hope to get an answer. StackOverflow users aren't magicians.

Comment: from the vagrant tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the support, I actually did uninstall the vagrant totally from my PC (Not repairing). Deleted the existing folder and all related to it.
Reinstalled it and it got that particular issue fixed.
Thanks !